# Align items in a stack panel?

Tags: wpf, layout, wpf-controls, stackpanel, alignment

I was wondering if I can have 2 controls in a horizontal-oriented StackPanel so that the right item should be docked to the right side of the StackPanel.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock>Left</TextBlock>
    <Button Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Right<Button>
</StackPanel>
```

In the snippet above I want the Button to be docked to the right side of the StackPanel.

Note: I need it to be done with StackPanel, not Grid etc.

Comment: You explicitly mention no grids, but that is exactly how I accomplished this.  I'll be interested to see if someone else has a non-grid answer for your question that fits my own needs.

Comment: yeah, i someone just gave me a project full of stack panels in this way, that's how he wants it to be fix it.

Comment: I know this is (extremely) late, but could you not put a dockpanel within the stackpanel?

Comment: @Kian, you are absolutely right with your comment, I thought of it myself, tried, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

You can achieve this with a `DockPanel`:

```
<DockPanel Width="300">
    <TextBlock>Left</TextBlock>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right">Right</Button>
</DockPanel>
```

The difference is that a [`StackPanel` will arrange child elements into single line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx) (either vertical or horizontally) whereas a [`DockPanel` defines an area where you can arrange child elements either horizontally or vertically, relative to each other](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.aspx) (the `Dock` property changes the position of an element relative to other elements within the same container. Alignment properties, such as `HorizontalAlignment`, change the position of an element relative to its parent element).

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments you can also use the `FlowDirection` property of a `StackPanel`. See @D_Bester's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46852788/40347).

Comment: this is what I meant with the 'etc.' I guess the answer is no, and will have to do it the tough way, read my comment for JMD above

Comment: Well, StackPanel simply can't do the layout that you want. A Grid will give you the most flexibility, but a change from StackPanel to DockPanel doesn't seem too difficult.

Comment: There is no DockPanel in Windows 8, any other solutions ?

Comment: @DirkVollmar Actually StackPanel works quite well, see my answer.

Comment: if you want to let item align right most, set `LastChildFill="False"` that is `<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599290/4573839

Answer (score 77):

Yo can set `FlowDirection` of `Stack panel` to `RightToLeft`, and then all items will be aligned to the right side.

Comment: Note however that this changes (reverses) the order of the controls in the StackPanel.

Comment: @slattery If FlowDirection is a problem just put in another StackPanel and specify the FlowDirection. See my answer.

Comment: @rumblefx0: note, the DockPanel also reverses the order of the controls, if they are docked to  the right or to the bottom. This is because the first control, is docked first.

Answer (score 39):

For those who stumble upon this question, here's how to achieve this layout *with* a `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Server:"/>
    <TextBlock Text="http://127.0.0.1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

creates

```
Server:                                                                   http://127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 21):

Could not get this working using a DockPanel quite the way I wanted and reversing the flow direction of a StackPanel is troublesome. Using a grid is not an option as items inside of it may be hidden at runtime and thus I do not know the total number of columns at design time. The best and simplest solution I could come up with is:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <!-- Right aligned controls go here -->
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This will result in controls inside of the StackPanel being aligned to the right side of the available space regardless of the number of controls - both at design and runtime. Yay! :)

Comment: If FlowDirection is a problem just put in another StackPanel and specify the FlowDirection. See my answer.

Comment: I think this is a much cleaner solution than messing with nested flow directions

Answer (score 8):

This works perfectly for me. Just put the button first since you're starting on the right. If FlowDirection becomes a problem just add a StackPanel around it and specify FlowDirection="LeftToRight" for that portion. Or simply specify FlowDirection="LeftToRight" for the relevant control.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <Button Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="3">Right</Button>
    <TextBlock Margin="5">Left</TextBlock>
    <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
        <my:DatePicker Height="24" Name="DatePicker1" Width="113" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" />    
    </StackPanel>
    <my:DatePicker FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="24" Name="DatePicker1" Width="113" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" />    
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Left"  />
    <Button Width="30" Grid.Column="1" >Right</Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: For my content, I used Width="*" on the first columnDefinition, and Width="Auto" on the second columnDefinition. This way, the first one takes up all the space less what the second column needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a problem like the one I had where labels were centered in my vertical stack panel, make sure you use full width controls.  Delete the Width property, or put your button in a full-width container that allows internal alignment.  WPF is all about using containers to control the layout.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock>Left</TextBlock>
    <DockPanel>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right">Right</Button>
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

[Vertical StackPanel with Left Label followed by Right Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFsh3.png)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

for windows 10
use relativePanel instead of stack panel, and use

> relativepanel.alignrightwithpanel="true"

for the contained elements.

Answer (score -9):

Maybe not what you want if you need to avoid hard-coding size values, but sometimes I use a "shim" (Separator) for this:

```
<Separator Width="42"></Separator>
```