# DockPanel.Dock="Right" is not working for single control on Maximized window?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am using DockPanel.Dock for docking controls at the specific place(i.e left/right). The problem is my controls are not docking according to the DockPanel.Dock position.

Below is the code for single control with `DockPanel.Dock="Right"`

```
    <DockPanel>

         <TextBlock
              Text            ="Left1"
              Margin          ="5"
              DockPanel.Dock  ="Left"
              Style           ="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
              />

         <TextBlock
              Text            ="Left2"
              Margin          ="5"
              DockPanel.Dock  ="Left"
              Style           ="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
              />

         <TextBlock
              Text            ="Right1"
              Margin          ="5"
              DockPanel.Dock  ="Right"
              Style           ="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
              />

   </DockPanel>
```

[image]
code for multiple controls with `DockPanel.Dock="Right"`

```
    <DockPanel>

         <TextBlock
              Text            ="Left1"
              Margin          ="5"
              DockPanel.Dock  ="Left"
              Style           ="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
              />

         <TextBlock
              Text            ="Left2"
              Margin          ="5"
              DockPanel.Dock  ="Left"
              Style           ="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
              />

         <TextBlock
              Text            ="Right1"
              Margin          ="5"
              DockPanel.Dock  ="Right"
              Style           ="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
              />

         <TextBlock
              Text            ="Right2"
              Margin          ="5"
              DockPanel.Dock  ="Right"
              Style           ="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
              />

   </DockPanel>
```

[image]

**Expecting Output:**

[image]

Any idea or thought will be appreciated.  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should make use of the `LastChildFill` property:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">

    <TextBlock
      Text            ="Left1"
      Margin          ="5"
      DockPanel.Dock  ="Left"
      />

    <TextBlock
      Text            ="Left2"
      Margin          ="5"
      DockPanel.Dock  ="Left"
      />

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <TextBlock
      Text            ="Right1"
      Margin          ="5"
      />
    <TextBlock
      Text            ="Right2"
      Margin          ="5"
      />

  </StackPanel>


</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine for me. But one more issue I have. Issue is while I am reducing the size of the window it should clip from the right most control but it is clipping from the "Right1" control, i.e. last placed control. Do you have any idea how to clip from the right most control?

Answer (score 13):

This is happening because the **`LastChildFill`** property of `DockPanel` is defaulted to `true`. For your desired output, **set it to `false`**.

As per `MSDN`:

*If you set the LastChildFill property to true, which is the default setting, the last child element of a DockPanel always fills the remaining space, regardless of any other dock value that you set on the last child element. To dock a child element in another direction, you must set the LastChildFill property to false and must also specify an explicit dock direction for the last child element.*

Sample UI and XAML with usage of DockPanel:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" WindowTitle="DockPanel Sample">
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Border Height="25" Background="SkyBlue" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      <TextBlock Foreground="Black">Dock = "Top"</TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Height="25" Background="SkyBlue" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      <TextBlock Foreground="Black">Dock = "Top"</TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Height="25" Background="LemonChiffon" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
      <TextBlock Foreground="Black">Dock = "Bottom"</TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Width="200" Background="PaleGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
      <TextBlock Foreground="Black">Dock = "Left"</TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
      <TextBlock Foreground="Black">This content will "Fill" the remaining space</TextBlock>
    </Border>
  </DockPanel>
</Page>
```

[image: XAML Sample]

If you dont want above behaviour, set LastChildFill="False" in above XAML sample and watch the result.

Comment: Yeah you are true and its working fine for me also. But one more issue I have. Issue is while I am reducing the size of the window it should clip from the right most control but it is clipping from the "Right1" control, i.e. last placed control. Do you have any idea how to clip from the right most control?

Comment: @SharpUrBrain Yes, for the other issue, change the sequence of placing the controls in your XAML, the docking happens in the sequence you use in your XAML to define the control elements. The LastChildFill property applies to the last XAML element in your XAML and, also remember the sequence of declaring your XAML elements is very important in DockPanel docking, always. Watch this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcQg4FxFi-g

Comment: I agree what you said above, but in my code for multiple controls with DockPanel.Dock="Right", the third control(i.e. Right2) placed at the right most and in code behind the fourth control(i.e. Right1) Placed last by sequence. So while reducing the size of the window it is clipping "Right1" control first rather it clipping the "Right2" control.

Comment: @SharpUrBrain Thats the correct behaviour, the first element in sequence with Dock=Right (which is Right1) will Dock to right most space, and then the next element in sequence with Dock=Right (which is Right2) will take the remaining space. For your desired output, declare your XAML elements so that the Right2 is declared in XAML before Right1..Hope that helps..!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions and ideas and also for the video you shared.

Answer (score 3):

Add HorizontalAlignment="Right" as mentioned below

```
     <TextBlock
          Text            ="Left1"
          Margin          ="5"
          DockPanel.Dock  ="Left"
          Style           ="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
          />

     <TextBlock
          Text            ="Left2"
          Margin          ="5"
          DockPanel.Dock  ="Left"
          Style           ="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
          />

     <TextBlock
          Text            ="Right1"
          Margin          ="5"
          DockPanel.Dock  ="Right"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          Style           ="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
          />

     <TextBlock
          Text            ="Right2"
          Margin          ="5"
          DockPanel.Dock  ="Right"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          Style           ="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
          />
```

Comment: ionden, answered code worked for me. Anyways, thanks for your participation and ideas. It is also helpful for me.