# Trying to get element alignment correct in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to get the first label and text box to align to the left side of the screen, and the second label and text box to align to the right side of the screen.   What am I missing here?  The second set of controls will not align to the right.

Thanks in advance!

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Active Profile"></Label>
                <TextBox Name="activeProfileName" Width="100" Height="20"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                <Label Content="Create A New Profile"                        
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Label>
                <TextBox Name="activeProfileNamey"
                         Width="100" Height="20"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aligning controls on both left and right side in a stack panel in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150914/aligning-controls-on-both-left-and-right-side-in-a-stack-panel-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outter `StackPanel` is your problem. Use `Grid` instead. Your question is actually a duplicate of the [Aligning controls on both left and right side in a stack panel in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150914/aligning-controls-on-both-left-and-right-side-in-a-stack-panel-in-wpf)

Here is the code with `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Active Profile"></Label>
                <TextBox Name="activeProfileName" Width="100" Height="20"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
            <Label Content="Create A New Profile"                        
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Label>
            <TextBox Name="activeProfileNamey"
                       Width="100" Height="20"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The code does not work.  It has the same behavior as the the code I posted.

Comment: Actually, if you change the column definition of the column from 'Auto' to '*', it works as expected.  Thanks zmechanic!!!