# WPF: why is the button stays on the left side?

Tags: wpf, button, alignment, stackpanel

I have this WPF button in my StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="12" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="LightGray" Height="40">
            <Button x:Name="btnSave" Click="btnSave_Click" Content="{x:Static res:Strings.ToolPanelEditView_Button_Save}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</StackPanel>
```

For some reason, the button shows on the left although I set its `HorizontalAlignment` to `Right`:

[image]

How can I make my save button show on the right?

P.S. when I change the StackPanel's `HorizontalAlignment` to `Right` instead of `Stretch`, the button does show on the right like it should (but then the gray background of the StackPanel does not stretch either...

Comment: Try using a `Grid` instead of a `StackPanel`

Comment: I didn't show it on the snippset, but I have an additional button there (cancel button). If I change the `StackPanel` to `Vertical` it will make those buttons be one above the other...

Answer (score 0):

I think that a `Grid` is more appropriate for your case

```
 <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="LightGray" Height="40">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btnSave" Grid.Column="1" Content="Save"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  />
        <!--Your Other Button Grid.Column="2"-->
    </Grid>
```

or you could as well replace the `stackPanel` with a [DockPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023201/align-items-in-a-stack-panel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DockPanel as container, stretch it and dock your button to the right side

```
    <DockPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="12" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="LightGray" Height="40">
      <Button Content="Save" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
      <Button Content="Cancel" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    </DockPanel>
```