# Aligning Elements within a StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel

I have a stack panel which has a Geometry button , text block and two Flat Buttons .. Even though I have given each of these elements individual horizontal alignments they seem to be all stacked from my Left hand side ...

I want my Geometry button and Text block to be aligned towards the Left hand  side and the Flat Button Aligned towards the Right hand Side of the stack panel .

As of now they are all lined up from the left hand side in their respective order

Why hasn't XAML picked up my alignements? Anything I can do about it?

Appreciate your help

Here is my code

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <GeometryButton    Command="{}" 
                                   Geometry="{StaticResource {}"
                                   ToolTip="{}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

                <TextBlock 
                              Text="{}" 
                              Style="{}"
                              Margin="0,10,10,10"
                              Foreground="Black"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>


                <FlatButton Command="{}"
                               Content="{}" 
                               Style="{}"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                               IsDefault="True"
                               Margin="0"
                               MinWidth="80"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               />

                <FlatButton Command="{}"
                               Content="{}" 
                               Style="{}"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                               MinWidth="80"
                               Margin="10,0,0,0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               />
            </StackPanel>
```

**EDIT :-** 
My Expected output is something like the Below ...

Also using Grid is not an Option for me

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
| [Geo Button] [Text Block]               [Flat Button][Flat Button]|
|                                                                   |
|                                                                   |
|                                                                   |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is your expected output is FlatButton aligned with Geometry Button and TextBlock on each end side?

Comment: StackPanel with Horizontal Alignment - will be setting all the items in a Row (if window width allows). The per element HoriZontalAlignment will align that Item (within its Drawing bounds towards left or right). I guess you are confused between StackPanel and DockPanel.

Comment: My Expected Outcome is Geometry Button and Text Block alligned together on the left hand side and the two flat buttons alligned together on the right hand side @CodeRed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `StackPanel` you can use `Grid` with column definitions. Example:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button   
        Grid.Column="0"
        Margin="8"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="Button1"/>

    <TextBlock 
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="8"
        Text="TextBlock" 
        Style="{Binding}"
        Foreground="Black"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


    <Button 
        Grid.Column="3"
        Margin="8"
        Content="Button2" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <Button 
        Grid.Column="4"
        Margin="8"
        Content="Button3" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Output:
[image]

**EDITED**

Another solution:

```xml
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Geo Button" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6"/>
        <Button Content="Text Block" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Flat Button" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6"/>
        <Button Content="Flat Button" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Using Grid Is not an Option for me as I have alread Used some Grid.  
This Required stack panel is actually inside a Grid (Grid.Row ="2")

Comment: Why you can't use `Grid` control? I think the `Grid` is best and easy solution for your question.

Comment: your Second solution with the docpanel was perfect , Hence I will mark it right..

Comment: Just out of curiousity how can I work this around using Grid control ?

Comment: Also I cant Undersand why the Dock panel is a good approach for this and the stack panel doesn't work ..... Really appreciate if you can explain that to me as well

Answer (score 1):

If your expected output is like this:

```
 --------------------------------------
| [Geo Button]                         |
| [Text Block]                         |
|                         [Flat Button]|
|                         [Flat Button]|
 --------------------------------------
```

Then you need to change your `Orientation` to `Vertical` instead of `Horizontal`.

However, if you want this:

```
 --------------------------------------
| [Geo Button]            [Flat Button]|
| [Text Block]            [Flat Button]|
 --------------------------------------
```

It is either:

1. Change the `Margin` of the `Flat Button`'s while still using the code above (I personally don't recommend this); or
2. Use `Grid` or `DockPanel`, try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2023201/10763029) for the codes and more explanations

I partially made your expected output with this:

```
<Grid Height="100" Background="Red">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
        //...
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        //...
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Partially**, because I don't have the resources for `FlatButton` and `Geo Button`, I only used regular `Button`'s. Take **note** that you need to set `VerticalAlignment` property to `Center` for `<TextBlock>`.

Comment: Kindly Look at the Edited Question @CodeRed

Answer (score 0):

A `DockPanel` should work for that. Try this:

```
<DockPanel Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <Button  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="GeoButton" Height="20" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="TextBlock" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    <Button  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Flat Button1" Height="20" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <Button  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Flat Button2" Height="20" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
</DockPanel>
```

[image]